# switched from query_posts to WP_query, not working now?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-query

So I had asked (in retrospect a pretty non-question) at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49705/a-little-help-cleanup-from-a-real-coder/49712#49712 and one of the comments was to not use query_posts and instead use WP_Query.  So I did a little digging and tried to implement that, now the code isn't working fully.  The MultiPostThumbnails isn't pulling the img I'm only getting the the_post_thubnail not additional img. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function efs_get_slider(){

    $slider= '<div id="ctslider">
                <div class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">';

    $my_posts = new WP_Query();
    $efs_query= "post_type=slider-image";
    $my_posts->query($efs_query);


    if($my_posts->have_posts()) : while ($my_posts->have_posts()) : $my_posts->the_post(); 

        $flexID = $my_posts->ID;
        $img1= wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id($flexID),'full',0 );
        $imagemain =  preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $img1 );

        if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
            $image_name = 'feature-image-2';
            if (MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('slider-image', $image_name)) {
                $image_id = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id(
                    'slider-image',
                    $image_name,
                    $flexID
                );
                $attr = array('class' => "secondaryslider");
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'full', false, $attr );
                $imagesecondary = preg_replace(
                    '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/',
                    "",
                    $image
                );
            }
        };

        $cttitle = get_the_title();
        $ctexcerpt = get_the_excerpt();

        $slider.='<li><div class="fourcol secondaryimg">'.$imagesecondary.'</div>';
        $slider.='<div class="threecol flex-caption"><h3>'.
            $cttitle.'</h3><p>'.$ctexcerpt.'</p></div>';
        $slider.='<div class="fivecol last">'.$imagemain.'</div></li>';


    endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();


    $slider.= '</ul>
    </div></div>';

    return $slider;
}
```

Comment: What point is it failing at? Does it not get `$image_id`? Or is it after that?

Comment: yes, it's not getting the $image_id...it's like it's not passing the post ID to the MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id

Comment: does `get_the_ID()` work if you try to execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MultiPostThumbnails, but I suspect your problem is:

```
$flexID = $my_posts->ID;
```

That code appears to be trying to get the ID of the WP_Query object itself. I don't think that exists. Even if it does, it won't do you much good.

Rather, use this:

```
$flexID = get_the_ID();
```

That code gets the ID of the current post in the loop.

In general, make sure to review the [WP_Query codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You can tighten things up quite a bit. For instance, your whole query can be on one line:

```
$my_posts = new WP_Query( 'post_type=slider-image' );
```

Comment: +1 for the last line. I *think* the underlying problem is that the `new WP_Query()` is instantiated *without the custom arguments*. To use custom args, the construct should be `$my_query = new WP_Query( $args )`.

Comment: mrwweb, that did the trick...AND it explained what I was missing.  my_posts->id getting the id of the wp_query...oi.  And, cleaned up a few lines.  @m0r7if3r looks like you were on the right track.  Now I'm going to read up on get_the_ID() vs $post->ID or whatever the hell I was trying to do!  And, Chip, I was able to get it to work before I cleaned up the custom args, so it did work by instantiating w/o the custom args, but...cleaner code all on one line. Thanks!!